# partial derivative over product of multiple variables

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I was wondering how one would calculate a partial differential over a product for example $\frac{\partial xy^{2}}{\partial a}$ with $a=xy$ My issue being that defining $xy^{2}$ as $ay$ or $\frac{a^{2}}{x}$ will give different results.

Comment: partial derivatives are ambiguous unless you define which variables are taken as independent. If you use $xy^2$ and $x$ as variables it is different than if you use $xy^2$ and $y$ as variables.

Comment: Thank you so this is ambiguous unless I define $$\frac{\partial xy^{2}}{\partial xy}\mid x $$

Comment: Indeed, there are many texts which do not make this notation explicit. For example, a popular hwk is $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 1$ which necessarily means the independent variables are taken as $y,z$ and $z,x$ and $x,y$ respectively.... sometimes authors just let context demand the interpretation. I like the bar notation to be explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there are two answers. Here is a notation to reflect this:
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\bigg{|}_x \qquad \text{vs.} \qquad \frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\bigg{|}_y $$
Take $f=x$ as an example,
$$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial a}\bigg{|}_x = 0 \qquad \text{vs.} \qquad \frac{\partial x}{\partial a}\bigg{|}_y = \frac{\partial}{\partial a}\bigg{|}_y\left( \frac{a}{y} \right) = \frac{1}{y}. $$

Comment: See page 419 of http://www.supermath.info/CalculusIIIf2014.pdf for much more on these sort of calculations.

Comment: probably meant is p.219

Comment: @user142523 indeed! Thanks for the correction.